# hyperref not detecting theorem counter/theorem number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems

Currently, my theorems are indexed as `Theorem {chapter}{section}{number}`, e.g. `Theorem 1.5.15` is the 15th theorem in Chapter 1, Section 5. However, when referencing these using `hyperref`, the counter is dropped. To reference `Theorem 1.5.15`, the link is only `1.5`.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter.}
\section{Section.}

\label{thm: Amazing.}\begin{theorem} Amazing!
\end{theorem}

\label{thm: Wow.}\begin{theorem} Wow!
\end{theorem}

By Theorem \ref{thm: Wow.} ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Spaces in label names are possible, but should not be used, however

Comment: since you're using `amsthm`, a better way to indicate the numbering of theorems is to specify `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`.  (read the `amsthm` user's guide -- `texdoc amsthdoc`.)  `\numberwithin` isn't as reliable in this situation.  but the real problem, as identified in the answers, is the position of the `\label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\label` command for numbered environments should appear **inside** inside the environment in general, since `\refstepcounter` (increasing the relevant counter) sets `\@currentlabel`, which is only a macro defined by `\protected@edef`, so `\@currentlabel` gets lost after the group formed by the environment.

A `\label` following after `\end{....}` will grab the last global `\@currentlabel`, in this case the section value, i.e. `1.1`.

Using the `cleveref` package, it would be possible to say `\Cref{lem: Wow}` and `Theorem 1.1.2` would appear automatically, i.e. without writing `Theorem` explicitly.

Although possible, spaces in label names are not recommended.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter.}
\section{Section.}

\begin{theorem} Amazing! \label{lem: Amazing.}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} Wow! \label{lem: Wow.}
\end{theorem}

By Theorem \ref{lem: Wow.} ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Does this hold for chapters, sections, etc.? That is, should I be writing this as `\label{ch:ex}\chapter{Chapter.}` or `\chapter{Chapter.}\label{ch:ex}`?

Comment: @user160653:  `\chapter`, then `\label`. `\chapter` etc. are not forming groups where `\@currentlabel` can be lost, but in general `\label` must appear **after** such macros, not before, in environment it should be **inside**, but again, not before.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- see the recommendation in my comment to the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, but the real issue is the wrong placement of the `\label` ...